# Exception when calling FindByBadPasswordAttempt

Tags: c#, passwords, userprincipal

I'm trying the last time when my windows password was written incorrect. And to do it I use UserPrincipalSearcher:

```
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
var v = UserPrincipal.FindByBadPasswordAttempt(pc, DateTime.Now, MatchType.LessThan);
```

But I get NotSupported exception in the second line of code. What is the problem?

Comment: Can you show the complete stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

The method expects a date in UTC format. Although not noted in the help files, I would imagine that a wrong date format can be a reason for this exception.

Try to pass `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of just `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: the exception was NotSupported exception.

Comment: What happens if you try `UserPrincipal.Current.LastBadPasswordAttempt`?